# Why should I use Django model Manager?

Tags: django, django-models

Why is it necessary to create a subclass of model.Manager and assigning it to objects (or some another attribute) in a Model? I've finished some projects earlier without model.Manager. Is it a must to do so?

Comment: it is not really clear what are you asking about. Do you mean creating subclass of `models.Manager` and assigning it to `objects` (or some another attribute) in your Model? You are using manager anyway, because every Model has `objects` attribute by default, which you use to create and query your objects.

Comment: yes, creating  sub class of **model.Manager**

Comment: As documentation states,  "There are two reasons you might want to customize a Manager: to add extra Manager methods, and/or to modify the initial QuerySet the Manager returns." https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers.  If you don't need this,  you don't need custom manager.